# Reduced residue system from complete residue system

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, reduced-residue-system

Where can I read a proof of the following result? Online or textbook preferably.

If $\Gamma = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_m\}$ is a complete residue system modulo $m$, then $\{a_i \in \Gamma| g.c.d.(a_i, m) = 1\}$ is a reduced residue system modulo $m$.

Comment: Which definition of "reduced residue system" are you using?

Comment: George Andrew's in Number Theory. Each number is incongruent with a different one. Coprime with modulus. A number outside the set coprime with modulus is congruent to number in the set.

Comment: So {0, 1, ..., m-1} is a special case of complete residue system.

Comment: It is likely that this, if it occurs in a book, would be given as an exercise.

Comment: @André Nicolas If it's easy to prove, a proof in an answer would be welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $a_i$ such that $\gcd(a_i,m)=1$ are all relatively prime to $m$. Now  we  need to show  that if $0\le b\lt m$ and $\gcd(b,m)=1$, then $b\equiv a_i\pmod{m}$ for some $a_i$ such that $\gcd(a_i,m)=1$.

Because $\Gamma$ is a complete residue system, it follows that $b\equiv a_i\pmod{m}$ for some **unique** $a_i\in \Gamma$. We show that $\gcd(a_i,m)=1$. Suppose to the contrary that some $d\gt 1$ divides both $a_i$ and $m$. Since $b\equiv a_i\pmod{m}$, we have $m\mid (b-a_i)$, and therefore $d\mid (b-a_i)$. Thus $d\mid (b-a_i)+a_i$, and therefore $d\mid b$. This contradicts the fact that $\gcd(b,m)=1$.

Comment: Restricting b to the range 0..m-1 is not part of Prof. Andrew's definition, but doesn't seem to be used in your proof?

Comment: It is indeed not used. The argument shows that any $b$ relatively prime to $m$ is congruent to some $a_i$ with $\gcd(a_i,m)=1$. I used $b$ between $0$ and $m-1$ for concreteness.